# Undesirable rounding off of numbers in generated PHPexcel

Tags: mysql, excel, phpexcel

I am generating a downloadable excel file from mysql database using phpexcel. In that, there is a field having 18 digit number, which in the mysql, it is defined as `Bigint`. The number is defined as a hyperlink in the code. Now, there is the following problem -

The last 4 digits of the number hyperlink are displayed as `0000` although on clicking the number hyperlink, it is opening correctly. Example `860814069447613475` is shown as `860814069447610000` in the generated excel

Here is my code -

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A'.(string)$n)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(
        PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER
    );

$n = 2;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.(string)$n, 
$row['t_id']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.(string)$n, 
$row['t_text']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.(string)$n, 
$row['user_name']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.(string)$n, 
$row['description']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.(string)$n 
,$row['time']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.(string)$n, 
$row['place']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A$n:F$n")->getAlignment()-
 >setWrapText(true);


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('A'.(string)$n)
    ->getHyperlink()
    ->setUrl('http://t.com/'.$row['user_name'].'/status/' . $row['t_id']);

    // Config
$link_style_array = [
  'font'  => [
    'color' => ['rgb' => '0000FF'],
    'underline' => 'single'
  ]
];

// Set it!
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.(string)$n)->applyFromArray($link_style_array);
    $n++;
}
```

Comment: Excel's precision is 15 digits.  If you need to display digits to a higher degree of precision, you will need to store them in Excel as text (and the cell must be formatted as text before you enter the string of digits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found code which worked for me -

```
setCellValueExplicit('A'.(string)$n, $row['t_id'], 
PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```